# Is savetrees incompatible with the author option in todonotes?

Tags: todonotes, savetrees

I am having some compatibility issues with the savetrees and todonotes packages.  I am trying to set the author of a `todo` command.  Normally this works fine, but if I also have the savetrees package loaded, I get a tikz error.  Any ideas on how to get this to work correctly?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

Get savetrees and todonotes to play nicely together.\todo[author=Jeff]{TDB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This compiles without error for me (TL 2018).

Comment: I don't get an error on MikTeX as well.

Comment: I was using TeX Live 2017.  When I updated to TeX Live 2018, everything worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.